# Why does the compiler implicit type casting not work for literal-typed properties which are implementations of an extended interface?

Tags: typescript

Why does the compiler implicit type casting not work for literal-typed properties which are implementations of an extended interface?

Example:

```
// typescript 3.4.5

interface INumContainer {
  num?: 1 | 2;
}

class myClass implements INumContainer {
  // does not compile
  // error TS2416: Property 'num' in type 'myClass' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'INumContainer'.
  //   Type 'number' is not assignable to type '1 | 2 | undefined'.
  num = 1;

  anotherNum: 1 | 2 = 1; // compiles
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class members are not [contextually typed](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) by the types they are declared to extend or implement, at least as of TS3.7.  The `extends` or `implements` declarations do result in type *checking* of the extending/implementing class, but this happens later.  This has been a pain point for a long time.

What's happening here is that literal types like `1` or `2` are widened to containing types like `number`, [unless they are in a non-widening context](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10676).  And since `myClass.num` is not contextually typed by `INumContainer["num"]`, it gets widened to `number`, which is seen to be incompatible.

The original issue filed about this for properties is [microsoft/TypeScript#3667](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3667). There [was an attempt](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/6118) to fix it, but [it was eventually rejected/abandoned](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/6118#issuecomment-216595207) because of some poor interoperability with some real-world code libraries.

And not much has happened since.  It seems that the currently open issue on this topic is [microsoft/TypeScript#32082](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32082), so if you want to see this addressed you might want to go to that issue and give it a  or some other show of support.

Until then, you'll just have to redundantly annotate your initializers.  Sorry I don't have a better answer for you.  Hope that helps; good luck!